# Side effects of changing question's title?

Tags: support, reputation, specific-user-account

I edited the title of one my old questions and then I noticed that my reputation points got reduced by 48 points. Are those two events correlated?

Comment: It's possibly because after you edit a question, it becomes active, and comes to the attention of users browsing active questions. Then, it might receive new up-/down-votes.

Comment: Thanks Sadeq. Actually, that question got one more vote and became 7 upvotes.

Comment: I can't see any reason for the reduction. I suggest you look at your answers to make sure that a question that you have answered previously has not been deleted. Btw, I can recalculate your reputation to make sure it is up-to-date if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, when questions get deleted, users who had originally provided answers lose those points. So I'm more inclined to think the events weren't correlated.